# Trace function which is declared inside another function

Tags: r, trace

I have the following code:

```
abc <- function() {
    def <- function() { }
    def_enter <- function() { print("def_enter") }
    def_exit <- function() { print("def_exit") }
    trace(def, def_enter, exit = def_exit)
    def()
}

abc_enter <- function() { print("abc_enter") }
abc_exit <- function() { print("abc_exit") }

trace(abc, abc_enter, exit = abc_exit)

abc()
```

I expect the output like this:

```
> abc()
Tracing abc() on entry 
[1] "abc_enter"
Tracing def() on entry
[1] "def_enter"
Tracing def() on exit
[1] "def_exit"
Tracing abc() on exit 
[1] "abc_exit"
NULL
```

But get such output:

```
> abc()
Tracing abc() on entry 
[1] "abc_enter"
Tracing function "def" in package "base"
Tracing abc() on exit 
[1] "abc_exit"
NULL
```

Is it possible to get output which I expect? How I can fix the code above?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the environment on which the function in `trace` is called.
Just mention it in the argument `where` of trace in the definition of `abc`:

```
abc <- function() {
    def <- function() { }
    def_enter <- function() { print("def_enter") }
    def_exit <- function() { print("def_exit") }
    trace(def, def_enter, exit = def_exit, where=environment())
    def()
}
```

And by calling `abc`, you will get the expected result:

```
#>abc()
#Tracing abc() on entry 
#[1] "abc_enter"
#Tracing function "def" in package ".GlobalEnv"
#Tracing def() on entry 
#[1] "def_enter"
#Tracing def() on exit 
#[1] "def_exit"
#Tracing abc() on exit 
#[1] "abc_exit"
#NULL
```